# Handle touch events before click events with jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch, dom-events

I am building a gallery slider using jQuery and some [plugin](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) (Best I could find fitting my problem). However, the gallery is mainly made of image links. When the user tries to slide by touching these, nothing happens. When I turned the `<a>` tags into `<span>`, the slider works fine when touching these.

Since the images make up a big part of the gallery and the white space is so tiny, many users would have trouble sliding it. How can I get jQuery to handle touch events before click events, so that the swiping is always working?

Comment: Have you considered jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Not an option - I'm required to update an existing site with just this one new feature.

Comment: Touch events will always fire before click events. in iOS and Android devices, the touch event fires instantly, whereas the click event has a ~300ms delay.